# 4th Generation iPod Touch Differences

Tags: ipod-touch

Are there any hardware differences between the 8GB, 32GB and 64GB 4th Generation iPod Touches.

*Apart form the storage size.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only storage size is different. There is no evidence or claims that point to the contrary.